# Powershell exception executing sql statement with oledb provider and strings

Tags: string, powershell, oledbconnection

I suspect that there is something wrong with the strings and handling. tried reading about here-strings but i am confused.

This:

```
$connectionString = "Provider=IBMDA400;Data ..........;"
#
cls
$conn = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = $connectionString
#
#$sql= Get-Content -Path "F6161001-sql1.txt"
$sql = "select *  from f6161001 where left(bidag,3)='115'"
Write-Output $sql
$conn.Open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.Oledb.OledbCommand($sql,$conn)
$rdr = $cmd.Executereader()
$rdr.Read()
write-output $rdr.GetValue(0)
$conn.close()
```

throws:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "SQL0104: Token ,3 was not valid. Valid tokens: ) ,.
Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error was detected at token ,3.  Token ,3 is not a valid token.  A partial list of valid tokens is ) ,.  This list 
assumes that the statement is correct up to the token.  The error may be earlier in the statement, but the syntax of the statement appears to be 
valid up to this point. Recovery  . . . :   Do one or more of the following and try the request again: -- Verify the SQL statement in the area of 
the token ,3. Correct the statement.  The error could be a missing comma or quotation mark, it could be a misspelled word, or it could be related to 
the order of clauses. -- If the error token is <END-OF-STATEMENT>, correct the SQL statement because it does not end with a valid clause."
```

Also tried declaring $sql like this:

```
$sql = 
@"
select count(*) from f6161001 where left(bidag,3)='115'
"@
```

Comment: Your SQL dialect (IBM DB2, I gather?) may not have a `LEFT` function. Try `WHERE bidag LIKE '115%'`. In any case, your problem seems to be in the SQL statement, not the way it's invoked from Powershell. Does it work outside Powershell?

Comment: It works but i think it uses jdbc and odbc.. Originbal SQL statement is not that simple . It uses functions like : MOD,SUBSTRING,LEFT

Comment: but left exist: https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/db2/rbafzmstscale.htm#HDRSCALEFT

Comment: I did say "may". I have no experience with DB2. :-) If it is indeed DB2, you should add the appropriate tags (`sql` `db2`) so the experts can weigh in.